# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 106: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python

im trying to merge multiple ts file into one if i try to run it it gives me the

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 106: character maps to

```
count = 76
main = "tsPath/seg_768x432_725648_"

for x in range(count):
    z = main+str(x)+".ts"
    print(z)
    with open(output, 'wb') as f:
        with open(z) as fh:
            f.write(fh.read())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I see the problem now.

### Solution

Assuming that the files exist on your computer, the following code will work correctly:

```py
count = 76
main = "tsPath/seg_768x432_725648_"

with open(output, 'wb') as f:
    for x in range(count):
        z = main+str(x)+".ts"
        print(z)
        with open(z, 'rb') as fh:
            f.write(fh.read())
```

### What changes were made and why?

1. Notice that the loop is inside the `with` block of `open(output, 'wb')` not the other way round. This needs to be done because every time you open a file in `wb` mode, all the data that existed in the file earlier is erased (same with `w` mode as well). So, we only open the `output` file for writing once. This will allow you to accumulate the data from the files you are reading (*which is what you want to do*).
2. The `mode` parameter of the `open` function is set to `r`(read text) by default. You are reading binary data so use `rb` mode. (*Other answers got this point right but missed point #1*).

Answer (score 2):

You are opening `z` in text mode (that is the default), and Python tries to decode it with an encoding in which `0x8f` doesn't correspond to any character (that could be CP1252 if you're on Windows)

As you mean to manipulate binary data, as you open `output` in binary mode, open `z` in binary mode also:

```
with open(z, 'rb') as fh:
```

Answer (score 2):

The first file you opened was opened in `"wb"` mode
but the second file, as it was not specified was opened in `"r"`
and the `UnicodeDecodeError` happens because the decoder can't convert (understand) some bytes to a string in this codec, so to solve that, just change the

```
with open(z) as fh:
```

to

```
with open(z, "rb") as fh:
```

but if you want to copy files I suggest you use **shutil** module as following:

```
import shutil

count = 76
main = "tsPath/seg_768x432_725648_"

for x in range(count):
    z = main+str(x)+".ts"
    print(z)
    shutil.copy(z, output)
```